# Load file and parse document

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, web

I have a code for displaying whole document in a HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html>
    <head>
    <script>
      let openFile = function(event) {
        let input = event.target;
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(){
          let text = reader.result;
          let node = document.getElementById('output');
                node.innerText = text;
          console.log(reader.result.substring(0, 200));
        };
        reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
      };
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type='file' accept='text/plain' onchange='openFile(event)'><br>
    <div id='output'>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I need to load a document then display only strings I need - names and url like:

Document example:

```
#NAME:Elis:
http://elis.com
#NAME:Emma:
http://emma.com
```

Display:

```
<a href=http://elis.com>Elis</a>
<a href=http://emma.com>Emma</a>
```

Comment: What's your question? What are you getting stuck on?

Comment: I don't know how to write a code to parse file (document example) to get a result (Display)

Comment: Your document example lines have different format - 3-rd line has extra space after colon and there's no second semicolon.

Comment: It was a mistake, fixed

Comment: since your file doesn't have any proper structured format such as JSON or XML, or even ini, start by reading each line one at a time. Then, look into using regular expressions to find the part of the line you're interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let openFile = function(event) {
  let input = event.target;
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    let text = reader.result;
    let node = document.getElementById('output');
    // node.innerText = text;

    var resultText = "";
    lines = reader.result.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
    for (let i = 0; i < lines.length - 1; i += 2) {
      var matches = lines[i].match(/\#NAME:([^:]+)/);
      resultText += `<a href="${lines[i+1].trim()}">${matches[1].trim()}</a>\n`;
    }
    // innerText here only for demonstration purpose
    // use innerHTML for working code instead
    node.innerText = resultText;
    // node.innerHTML = resultText
  };
  reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
};
```

```html
<input type='file' accept='text/plain' onchange='openFile(event)'><br>
<div id='output'>
```

Comment: This is great code, but a problem is that it doesn't display characters <> --> <div id="output">&lt;a href="http://elis.com"&gt;Elis&lt;/a&gt;<br>&lt;a href="http://emma.com"&gt;Emma&lt;/a&gt;<br></div>

Comment: Did you try to replace `innerText` with `innerHTML`?

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = `#NAME:Elis:
http://elis.com
#NAME:Emma:
http://emma.com`;

const makeUpHrefs = str => {
    let arr = str.split(/\n#/);
    arr = arr.map(row => '<a href="' + row.match(/\n(.*)/)[1] + '">' + row.match(/NAME:(.*?):/)[1] + '</a>');
    return arr;
};
```

So, `makeUpHrefs(str)` will return array of html's:

```
<a href="http://elis.com">Elis</a>
<a href="http://emma.com">Emma</a>
```